# Changes in time zone rules

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

The state of Florida has approved the [Sunshine Protection Act](https://nypost.com/2018/03/07/florida-lawmakers-pass-bill-for-year-round-daylight-saving-time/) which eliminates DST in Florida.

What changes do I need to make to my .NET code so that it won't get the answer wrong when converting UTC DateTime to Florida local time?

Comment: And here, I was not even aware that Sunshine needed protection.

Comment: .Net gets its timezone information from Windows.  Just update Windows.  [Here is an example of such an update from 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3162835/june-2016-dst-and-time-zone-update-for-windows)  (Should I write this as an answer?)

Comment: It will show up here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dst2007/

Comment: The law hasn't been signed by the Governor as yet.  And then Congress would need to amend existing federal law.  So it will take a couple of years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make any code changes.

.Net gets its timezone information from Windows. Just update Windows.  Microsoft will release an update before the law goes into effect.

The update will be listed [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dst2007/) *(credit to @HansPassant)*

[Here is an example of such an update from 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3162835/june-2016-dst-and-time-zone-update-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 basic Rules regarding DateTimes:

1. Always store, transmit and retrieve UTC. Timezones? That is something .NET can deal with during output. After it asked Windows wich Timezone and Culture Format should be applied to that UTC value. You do not deal with Timezones, because [that way lies madness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).
2. Avoid storage, transmission and retreival as strings. Use DateTime types for as long as possible.
3. If you can not fullfill Rule 2 (XML or other Serialstion), at least pick a fixed culture and String Encoding at all Endpoints. You do not want to add those headaches to your issues.

In your case asuming you followed rule 1 and this is not a Server Application, just wait for Windows to Update it's Timezone/UST list. It is a UI job and .NET has very good connections to the Windows Systems responsible for this kind of stuff.

If this is a Server Application, each user can pick their own timezones. A minor change might be nesseary here. It really depends how you went about Internationalsiation.